# How to show that this series has a maximum at $x = 0$ using the "Descartesschen Regel"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, optimization

I am reading an old German paper, and at one step they mention that the function
\begin{equation*}
f(x) := \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(1+x)(k(k-1)^2 + (2+x)(1+x)^2)}{(k+x)^3 (k + 1 + x)^2}
\end{equation*}
defined on $x \in [0, 1]$ can be shown to have a maximum at $x = 0$ using an elementary application of the ''Descartesschen Regel'' (Descarte rule).

What is the Descarte rule that is mentioned here? Can the maximum at $x = 0$ be shown using an elementary method as the paper claime?

Comment: Could you please give a reference to this paper? I am German and could maybe understand from the context.